# Показ новых комментариев без перезагрузки

Tags: jquery, php, mysql, javascript

Хочу реализовать на сайте удобную переписку пользователей. Добавление нового комментария с ajax было сделать не сложно. Как реализовать показ новых комментариев по-оптимальнее? Пока придумал обращаться к БД каждые 5 секунд с проверкой количества записей, и если оно изменилось брать разницу изначального количества и нынешнего и делать запрос к БД c limit. Есть ли пути лучше?

Comment: Лучше timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Само направление верно, но есть несколько моментов:

1. 5 сек - имхо маловато
2. Сравнивать по количеству записей - неправильно (один юзер удалил свой коммент, а другой добавил - кол-во записей не изменилось - но изменились данные, также юзер может поправить коммент)

Так же, думаю, стоит подумать над реализацией временного хранилища данных: скрипт, отвечающий за выдачу комментов, не работает с БД, а работает с файлом, в котором есть метка создания этого файла и подготовленные для передачи данные. А вот сам файл готовится (перезаписывается) при реализации следующих операций - удаления, добавления и обновления комментов. Также аяксом передаем время предыдущих данных (берем из файла) - скрипт сравнивает значение меток - если одинаковые - данные не передаем, разные - данные передаем.

Comment: Можно для каждого коммента сделать свой id, и сравнивать не кол-во комментов, а id -шники