# Обновить другую страницу при помощи ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

К примеру, на одной странице добавляется запись с помощью `ajax`. Но на других страницах всё по-прежнему, до перезагрузки страницы. Как обновлять блок с записями на других страницах в тот момент, когда запись добавилась?

Comment: Добавляется запись, как я понимаю, в БД? Другие страницы подгружаются так же ajax-средствами? Как подгружается контент в "блок с записями"?

Хорошо бы как-то раскрыть тему ...

Comment: Записи в бд. Это одна и та же страница, просто открыта на разных компьютерах, разными пользователями. При перезагрузке страницы, записи добавляются через php, а потом уже ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, стоит отправлять каждую секунду запрос с проверкой добавилась ли новая запись.
Ну при загрузке страницы достать из базы айди последней записи и поместить её в яваскрипт переменную и потом каждую секунду по средством аякса проверять существуют ли в базе записи, у которых айди больше, чем в нашей переменнойю В случае, если существуют, то вернуть их и при помощи Джейкварри добавить.

Comment: Это не будет тормозить страницу?

Comment: Нет, не должно. Я так чат делал и работало всё просто на ура! и да когда мы добавили записи стоит обновить и нашу переменную)))

Comment: Спасибо попробую))

Comment: а сервак у вас не ляжет с запросами каждую секунду? сколько юзеров будет сидет на данном приложении?
И второе - а если запись удалили? но в это время еще не добавили новых записей - то ваш php скрипт не будет брать данные с таблицы, а следовательно и данные будут неактуальны? 
Так же дело с изменением записи - человек сначала ввел а затем исправил - опять пока данные недобавятся страница будет содержать неактуальные данные(

Comment: Никто ничего об удалении или изменении записи не говорил! Наезд на пустом месте(придумали причину и наехали). А на счёт ляжет ли сервер я не думаю. И вообще вы кроме как того чтобы раскритиковать ничем не помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Вот похожий вопрос -
[Показ новых комментариев без перезагрузки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/109070/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8). Там есть мой ответ.

Думаю, это решение подойдет и для Вас.